# Prove that $0$ is in the interior of the spectrum a surjective linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Suppose $T$ is a linear bounded operator on a Banach space $X$ over the complex field $\mathbb{C}$, and $T$ is surjective but not injective.
Prove that $0$ is an interior point of the spectrum of $T$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). More important: Show Your own efforts. What have You tried to solve the problem? See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)