# Zero is an interior point of a surjective bounded operator with nonempty kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory, spectral-theory

> Let $T$ be a linear bounded operator on a Banach space $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$, and $T$ is surjective but not injective. Then $0$ is an interior point of the spectrum of $T$.

I came across this question a few days ago. It has been closed, but I want to check my proof of the statement.

**Proof**

*Preparations:* $\ker T := Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$. We can take a factor $X/Y$ and the respective quotient map $Q$. It is well-known that $X/Y$ is Banach space w.r.t. the quotient norm $||x + Y|| = \inf_{y \in Y}||x + y||$. By the inverse mapping theorem $S := TQ$, which is bijective, has a bounded inverse. Denote $r = 2||S^{-1}|| > 0$. By the definition of the quotient norm $\forall x \in X$ $\exists x' \in X$ s.t. $Tx' = x$ and $||x'|| \leq r ||x||$. For any given $x \in X$ we will denote the corresponding $x'$ as $R(x)$. There are many vectors that fits, but we will assume that only one is chosen for each $x \in X$.

*Main part:*

Fix an arbitrary $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $|\lambda| \le (3r)^{-1}$. Fix an arbitrary $x_0 \in Y$ s.t. $||x_0|| = 1$. Denote $x_n = \lambda^n R^n(x_0)$, $n \in \mathbb N$. By the definition of $R$ $||x_n|| \leq (\lambda r)^n \le 3^{-n}$.

Consider an element $w \in X$ defined by the following absolutely convergent series:
$$
w = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n x_n.
$$
Since
$$
\left|\left|\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n x_n\right|\right| \leq \frac 12,
$$
$w$ is a nonzero vector.

Now we observe that
$$
(T + \lambda E) w = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n T x_n + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \lambda x_n = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n \lambda x_{n-1} + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \lambda x_n = 0.
$$

Hence $\ker (T + \lambda E) \neq 0$, so $-\lambda$ belongs to the spectrum of $T$ (moreover, it's in the point spectrum). **Q.E.D.**

Comment: @MartinArgerami I have found now that this statement (in this exact firm) is used in some paper with reference to the Taylor’s Introduction to Functional Analysis, where it has, I think, a slightly different, but equivalent, form. There’s no proof in this book, it is given as an exercise. Anyway, I haven’t found any obvious counterexample, that’s why I was interested.

Comment: My bad. $ \ \ $

Comment: +1 I voted to close the [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4178028/prove-that-0-is-in-the-interior-of-the-spectrum-a-surjective-linear-operator#comment8657930_4178028) question, since the poster did not show any effort, this is not the case here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is good. I'll just comment a few minor things.

- The map $S$ is not $TQ$. What you want to do is define $S(x+Y)=Tx$. This map is bounded and bijective, so invertible.
- You can take $r=\|S^{-1}\|$, you don't need the 2. You choose $Rx$ to be a representative of $S^{-1}x$ such that $\|Rx\|\leq\|S^{-1}x\|$. Then $$\|Rx\|\leq\|S^{-1}x\|\leq\|S^{-1}\|\,\|x\|=r\|x\|.$$
- You can take $|\lambda|< (2r)^{-1}$. Because this makes the sum starting at $k=1$, less than 1, while the first term has norm 1.
- You don't need the $(-1)^n$, they play no role.
- Your last computation will look nicer (to me, at least), if you write it in the form $Tw=\lambda w$ (after removing the $(-1)^n$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will look through it thoroughly a bit later

Comment: Yes, I agree with all those points, except the second one. I think, if $||S^{-1} x = y + Y$ and so $||y+Y|| \le ||S^{-1}|| ||x||$, it may happen that for some $x$ the inequality becomes equality. Then norms of all representatives can be strictly grater than $||S^{-1}|| ||x||$. Or is there something that I’m missing?

Comment: You are right. But you can do the argument with $\|Rx\|\leq(1+\varepsilon)\|S^{-1}x\|$, which allows you to take $|\lambda|< (2(1+\varepsilon)r)^{-1}$. As this can be done for any $\varepsilon>0$, in the end the whole thing works for $|\lambda|<(2r)^{-1}$.

Comment: yes, I see your point. In fact, this 2 we’re discussing was needed to avoid those technical details :)

Comment: and thanks again for your time and your answer!

Comment: No problem. I wasn't aware of this result, so it was nice to see. I'm very familiar with the fact that the left unilateral shift has the whole open unit disk as eigenvalues, but it was surprising that the result is so general.

Comment: yes, I was surprised too

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the conclusion, I post an improved version of the proof.

> Let $T$ be a linear bounded operator on a Banach space $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$, and $T$ is surjective but not injective. Then $0$ is an interior point of the spectrum of $T$.

**Proof**

*Preparations:* $\ker T := Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$. We can take a factor $X/Y$ and the respective quotient map $Q$. It is well-known that $X/Y$ is Banach space w.r.t. the quotient norm $||x + Y|| = \inf_{y \in Y}||x + y||$. By the universal property of quotients there exists (a unique) $S \in \mathscr B (X/Y, X)$ s.t. $SQ = T$. Since $T$ is surjective, $S$ is bijective, so by the inverse mapping theorem $S$ has a bounded inverse. Fix an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ and denote $r_\varepsilon = (1+\varepsilon)||S^{-1}|| > 0$. By the definition of the quotient norm $\forall x \in X$ $\exists x' \in X$ s.t. $Tx' = x$ and $||x'|| \leq r_\varepsilon ||x||$. For any given $x \in X$ we will denote the corresponding $x'$ as $R_\varepsilon(x)$. There are many vectors that fits, but we will assume that only one is chosen for each $x \in X$.

*Main part:*

Fix an arbitrary $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $|\lambda| < (2r_\varepsilon)^{-1}$. Fix an arbitrary $x_0 \in Y$ s.t. $||x_0|| = 1$. Denote $x_n = \lambda^n R^n_\varepsilon(x_0)$, $n \in \mathbb N$. By the definition of $R_\varepsilon$ $||x_n|| \leq (\lambda r_\varepsilon)^n < 2^{-n}$.

Consider an element $w \in X$ defined by the following absolutely convergent series:
$$
w = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty x_n.
$$
Since $\left|\left|\sum_{n = 1}^\infty x_n\right|\right| < 1$, $w \neq 0$.

Now we observe that
$$
T x_n = T \lambda^n R^n_\varepsilon(x_0) = \lambda^n R^{n-1}_\varepsilon(x_0) = \lambda x_{n-1}.
$$
Hence
$$
T w = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty T x_n  = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lambda x_{n-1} = \lambda\sum_{n = 0}^\infty x_{n} = \lambda w.
$$

Therefore, $\ker (T - \lambda E) \neq 0$, so $\lambda$ belongs to the spectrum of $T$. Moreover, we have proven that $\sigma_p (T) \supset \{\lambda \in \mathbb C \mid |\lambda| < (2||S^{-1}||)^{-1}\}$. **Q.E.D.**